# How to set my array value with axios response value

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I want to set my cats array to the axios response. I'm getting my axios response but when I check my console.log...my cats array is not getting set. How can I set my cats array from my axios response?

Thank you

```

```
data(){
   cats:[],
   ...
},
beforeMount(){
         axios.get(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/cats/`)
        .then(response => {
          self.cats = response.data.results; <----What should this be?
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
},
mounted () {
      console.log(this.cats);
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own..here is what I did. Replaced beforeMount with created and called axios there. While setting my search object inside axios.

```

```
    data(){
      cats:[],
      ...
    },
    created () {
      axios.get(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/cats/`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("before: "+ this.cats);
          this.cats = response.data.results;
          console.log("after: "+ this.cats);
          this.fuseSearch = new Fuse(this.cats, {keys: ['name', 'gender']})
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
    mounted () {
      console.log("mounted: " + this.cats);
    },
```

```